# Limiting results in different way

Tags: mysql

This my query

```
     $query="SELECT parent.name, parent.depth
        FROM  address AS node,
                address AS parent
        WHERE node.name LIKE '%".$name."%' AND   
        node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt   
        order by node.lft, parent.rgt";
```

this is my table structure:

```
name        |lft | rgt | depth|
------------+----+-----+------+
Australia   | 1  | 10  |  1   |
nsw         | 2  | 9   |  2   |
sydney      | 3  | 8   |  3   |
kensington  | 4  | 5   |  4   |
kingsford   | 6  | 7   |  4   |
------------+----+-----+---- -+
```

let us assume `$name`=k then the results will be

```
name        |depth|
------------+-----+
kingsford   | 4   |
sydney      | 3   | 
nsw         | 2   | 
Australia   | 1   |
kensington  | 4   | 
sydney      | 3   | 
nsw         | 2   | 
Australia   | 1   |
```

I will present them like this:

```
-->kensington, sydney, nsw, australia
-->kingsford, sydney, nsw, australia
```

I could not limit this to cover only 10 addresses at most. If I added `limit 2` for example it will not show the two addresses above. it will show this only `-->kensington, sydney`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the question is not too clear, but if I understand it correctly, I would use something like this:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(parent.name ORDER BY parent.depth DESC) AS name
FROM
  address AS node JOIN address AS parent
  ON node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt  
WHERE node.name LIKE '%k%'
GROUP BY node.name
LIMIT 10
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4b6e/9).

**Edit**

You might also want to use this, that returns the rows in your original format:

```
SELECT
  parent.name, parent.depth
FROM
  (SELECT name, lft FROM address WHERE name LIKE '%k%' LIMIT 10) AS node,
  address AS parent
WHERE
  node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt   
order by node.lft, parent.rgt
```

Comment: why are using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. It does nothing. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89c87/4/0

Comment: @Sami I used SUBSTRING_INDEX to get only the first 10 names before the comma, but the query returns less than 10, you can try to use 2 to see how it works... i am not sure if it is this exactly what you want

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. I am so sorry for my poor explanation

Comment: @Sami you're welcome :) i also edited my answer and added another solution, it's a different approach that returns the rows in your original format

Comment: Very appreciated :) I like the second solution more. Thank you again :)